# How do I assign variables to arrays inside a switch loop

Tags: java, arrays

How do I assign the variables 1 and 0 to the array, while looping to change the variable to be assigned to the next position in that array?

```
int number[] = new int[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    Scanner attendance = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inp = attendance.nextInt();
    int y = inp;
    switch (inp)
    {
    case 1:
        number[y] = 1;
        y--;
        break;
    case 0:
        number[y] = 0;
        y--;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: what variables you want to assign?

Comment: You need to add a tag for what language this is. It affects the syntax coloring and also helps those who can answer the question find the question.

Comment: It's Java? Do you mind adding the proper language tag?

Comment: You probably want to assign `number[i]`, not `number[y]`.  And I don't know what a "switch loop" is.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is currently setup unless the user is knowing to only use 0 or 1 your going to get an error due to the way the switch is setup make sure you have a default case as it will get all values outside the requested ones.

Another problem can be that someone puts say 23 for y.  Your going to get an ArrayOutOfBounds error.  This is due to that y is the position of where it will insert the 1 or 0.

In the case of you want it to go to the next place in the array do what David Wallace said and place a new variable dedicated to the array so that in the for loop it will be

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++;) {
```

Then have the numbers array change its position by marking the spot like

```
numbers[i] = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example you may be able to adapt:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverflow40268692 {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    final int number[] = new int[10];
    System.out.println("Please enter ten attendance numbers. One and zero are valid entries.");
    final Scanner attendance = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.println("Please enter attendance number for position " + i);
      final int inp = attendance.nextInt();
      switch (inp) {
        case 1:
        case 0:
          number[i] = inp;
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
          i--;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Collected data: " + Arrays.toString(number));
  }
}
```